# Prompting the user for a product number and quantity

Tags: java, beginner, homework

> Write a Java application that prompts the user for pairs of inputs of
>   a product number (1,2,3,4,5) and quantity of units sold (any integer)?
>
> Use a `switch` statement and a sentinel-controlled loop (i.e., a loop
>   that stops execution when an out-of-range value, such as -1, is input).
>
> All 15 items below are for a single purchase. There are five sets of
>   inputs as follows:
>
> ```
> Product 1       1 unit           (cost is $2.98 per unit)
> Product 2       2 units          (cost is $4.50 per unit)
> Product 3       3 units          (cost is $9.98 per unit)
> Product 4       4 units          (cost is $4.49 per unit)
> Product 5       5 units          (cost is $6.87 per unit)
> ```
>
> Your application must calculate and display the total retail value for
>   all the five pair of products sold.

---

```java
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Program3 {  

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    int productNo = 0;  
    double product1; 
    double product2;  
    double product3;  
    double product4;  
    double product5;  
    int quantity;  

    double totalSales = 0;   

    while(productNo !=0 )


        System.out.println("Enter product number 1-5 ");  
        productNo=input.nextInt();  

        System.out.println("Enter quantity sold ");  
        quantity = input.nextInt();  


        switch (productNo) {  

                case 1: product1 = 2.98;  
        totalSales+=(2.98*quantity);  
        break;  

                case 2: product2 = 4.50;  
        totalSales+=(4.50*quantity);  
        break;  

                case 3: product3 = 9.98;  
        totalSales+=(9.98*quantity);  
        break;  

                case 4: product4 = 4.49;  
        totalSales+=(4.49*quantity);  
        break;  

                case 5: product5 = 6.87;  
                totalSales+=(6.87*quantity);  
        break;  

    }  


    System.out.println(totalSales);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Errors**

- You had some misstyped curly brackets. Please double check your code next time before posting it here.
- `productNo` had 0 as initial value, the `while` checked `productNo != 0` meaning it will never perform an iteration. Instead the `while` should check against `-1` as was specified.
- You refered to `input` which was a `non-static` member. Meaning it can not be refered to from a `static` method. (As your `main` is.)

---

**double not for currency**

double should not be used to represent currency. You can read more about why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app). A short version; double (and float for that matter) is not accurate enough.

---

**Switch**

Now I can understand why they homework wanted you to study `switch` and `case` however you should know that there are better ways to solve the problem. Adding a `class Product` with an `id` and a `price`. You could also use a `Map<K, V>` to bind `productNo` to a `price`.

---

**Consistency**

Is there a reason why `Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);` is a field and not the `productNo` variables? If you want it as a field you can use the `final` keyword, to make sure that it never gets overwritten.

**Final version**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;  

public class Test
{
    private final static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    private final static BigDecimal product1 = new BigDecimal("2.98"); 
    private final static BigDecimal product2 = new BigDecimal("4.50");  
    private final static BigDecimal product3 = new BigDecimal("9.98");  
    private final static BigDecimal product4 = new BigDecimal("4.49");  
    private final static BigDecimal product5 = new BigDecimal("6.87");  

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        BigDecimal totalSales = new BigDecimal(0);

        int productNo = 0;
        while (productNo != -1 ) {
            System.out.println("Enter product number 1-5 ");  
            productNo = input.nextInt();  

            System.out.println("Enter quantity sold ");  
            BigDecimal quantity = new BigDecimal(input.nextInt());  

            switch (productNo) {
                case 1:
                    totalSales.add(product1.multiply(quantity));
                    break;  

                case 2:
                    totalSales.add(product2.multiply(quantity));
                    break;  

                case 3:
                    totalSales.add(product3.multiply(quantity));
                    break;  

                case 4:
                    totalSales.add(product4.multiply(quantity));
                    break;  

                case 5:
                    totalSales.add(product5.multiply(quantity));
                    break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(totalSales.toString());
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer*

There might be other areas to improve on. This is by no means a perfect fix of the code.

Comment: No need to write a disclaimer - partial reviews are just as good :) See [Is it ok to review only a part of the code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2321/64958)

Comment: It was more a note to the readers that there might be other areas to improve upon. That they shouldn't expect these improvements to perfect, if such a thing exists, the code.